# How to reduce the RPM of a DC motor

Tags: motor, dc-motor, rpm

I need a small 3-pole commutator motor with 4000 RPM @ 12 V and the best I can buy is 8000 RPM @ 12 V. I am considering buying an 8000 RPM motor and replacing the existing windings with thinner wire.

I have calculated that I can double the number of turns if I cut the cross-sectional area of the wire in half. At the same time, the resistance of the winding will quadruple. Consequently, the magnetic moment of a winding (at the same voltage) will halve.

What are the effects of such a replacement? Will the RPM be halved? How will this affect the torque?

Comment: Are you talking about a BLDC motor?

Comment: @JonathanS. No, motor a commutator with three poles.

Comment: what frequency do you mean? 12V is not a common AC source and DC has no frequency that you can depend on.  If you are talking about essentially building your own motor, there are a lot of factors at play, possibly more so on a brushed motor.  8k gears to 4k much easier than building your own.

Comment: @Abel Rotational frequency, 8000RPM = 133Hz.

Comment: I think there is some confusion here.  A DC motor does not use any frequency (Hz.)  Just a DC voltage.  Regardless, speed control of any motor is best suited to some sort of speed feedback, whether that be a generator, resolver, encoder, etc.  You can get close with a BLDC or AC servo motor, but even those have speed feedback in demanding applications.

Comment: @rdtsc The fact is that you can buy motors with differend RPMs at the same voltage.  My question is essentially whether it is possible to change RPM by changing windings of the motor.

Comment: Anything is possible. But unless you enjoy making a lot of extra work for yourself, with unpredictable results, why not just get what you really need in the first place?  It's fine if you want to learn motor rewinding, but this is not an easy subject.  It is compounded by the vagueness of the motor ("DC" and "3-pole" sound like two completely different motor types to me, and *how* those would be rewound is vastly different.)

Comment: @rdtsc I just can't get low-RMS motor of that size anywhere!  It is most common DC motor with a three pole comutator like this one https://www.tme.eu/si/en/details/pololu-1592/dc-motors/pololu/brushed-dc-motor-130-size-3v-17krpm/, if I am using wrong expressions, please help me correct them.

Comment: It would likely be easiest to use [gear reduction](https://www.worldwideelectric.net/articles/gear-reducers-101-back-to-the-basics/) on this motor.  If you know it spins at some speed (say 10000 RPM) and you want 4000 RPM, then 10000/4000 = 2.5 so you'd want a 2.5:1 gear reduction.  Torque multiplies when using gear reduction, so you'd also have about 2.5 times more torque.

Comment: @rdtsc If using gear reduction would be feasible (space restrictions, double shaft), I wouldn't ask this question...

Comment: Does “3 pole” in this context mean *3 phase*? I may be missing something but I don’t think it’s possible for a magnetic device like a motor to have an odd number of poles. 3 phase motors typically have 6 poles

Comment: @Ryan there are three contacts on the commutator.  Maybe "three segment commutator" would better describe the motor?

Comment: @Pygmalion Ok, I looked at the link, its just a regular DC motor. Just decrease the voltage till you get the speed you want. Rewinding it to change the speed is insanity! Have you never played with slot cars, trains, etc.?

Comment: Mabuchi Motor has this list of hobby brush motors: https://product.mabuchi-motor.com/result.html?t=1531210096. If you could publish a link to specifications for your selected motor then maybe I can make an answer with a sketch of how the input voltage level moves the operating point to a family of torque-speed curves. The speed of your motor depends on the rotational inertia of the load, during efforts to accelerate the inertial load, and the steady state speed depends on the rotational friction, so it is not straightforward to directly relate voltage to the rpm operating point.

Comment: FF-130SH DC 12V 4500 RPM Mini Motor Micro DC Motor Quiet High Torque For DIY Toy https://www.ebay.com/itm/194763599832?hash=item2d58d0afd8:g:1xwAAOSwV-ph7gRE

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully at the motor specifications to determine if 8000 RPM is the rated speed when delivering rated torque or the no-load speed. Most motors of this type are intended for toy and hobby use and sales information is poor. If 8000 RPM is the rated speed, consider operating at half of the rated voltage. That should provide something close to half the rated speed and 100% of rated torque.

> What are the effects of such a replacement? Will the RPM be halved? How will this affect the torque?

Doubling the number of turns doubles the back EMF for a given RPM. Cutting the wire cross section in half along with doubling the turns will quadruple the resistance. Half the current with twice the turns will result in about unchanged torque capability. The increased back EMF will result in about half the speed at the same torque and supply voltage. Half current and quadruple resistance will result in about double the previous voltage drop in the winding but the same power loss. The increased voltage drop will have some effect on the speed, but the back EMF is the predominant factor.

As pointed out by @Spehro Pefhany, doubling the full-torque voltage drop in the resistance with half the full-speed voltage will result in 4X change in percent speed for a given change in torque. Also the stall current is completely determined by the winding resistance since the back EMF is zero. That means stall torque of 1/4 the original. That will likely still be more than rated torque. Also in toy and hobby use, stall torque is often limited by power supply capability.

Comment: This is what I was going to say, if its just a standard DC motor, then decreasing the voltage will decrease the speed.

Comment: I use these motors for model railroading, which has a fixed top voltage of 12V. Usually the locomotives work at almost no-load speed, so this information is most important. As for the rest, I assume that you confirm my assumption that the speed is halved while claiming that the torque remains the same, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying..

Answer (score 1):

If you were successful in rewinding the motor, I think you'd basically end up with a higher voltage motor given the other fixed parameters.

At 4x the resistance the stall torque will be 1/4 and the open-loop change in speed with torque change will be 4x worse.

So you might as well just run the motor as-is at 1/2 voltage.

You could consider a closed-loop or compensated control. The former requires an RPM sensor, but you could also do compensation by sensing motor current and jacking the voltage up proportionally to compensate for the winding resistance. This might work well for a modest decrease in RPM like 2:1. The constant of proportionality should be chosen to almost null out the winding resistance (effectively inserting a negative resistance in series with the positive winding resistance).

---

Given the added information in comments, *if* voltage is unidirectional  **only** you could try a ~6V Zener diode in series with the motor and a 1N5819 diode directly across the motor (both reverse biased in normal operation)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHB8lf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The required current will be doubled, the power dumped in D1 mostly, which should be appropriately rated.

Comment: Well, I use these motors for model railroading, which has a fixed top voltage of 12V. I just want all locomotives to run at about the same speed at maximum voltage. Running at half voltage with a special controller is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

> I have calculated that I can double the number of turns if I cut the
> cross-sectional area of the wire in half. At the same time, the
> resistance of the winding will quadruple. Consequently, the magnetic
> moment of a winding (at the same voltage) will halve.
>
> What are the effects of such a replacement? Will the RPM be halved?

Yes.

> How will this affect the torque?

Torque constant is the inverse of velocity constant, so it will be doubled.
However as the resistance is quadrupled the stall current will be quartered, so the stall torque will be halved.

To get the original stall torque you have to double the voltage, and then the speed will be doubled too. So you end up with the same motor specs (power, torque, rpm) at 24 V as you had at 12 V before rewinding.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly my thinking. Knowing that power is torque times angular frequency, P = M * omega (omega = RPM /60*2*pi) and assuming that the power of the motor does not change when rewinding, the working torque should be doubled. On the other hand, the stall torque is definitely halved. I was not able to reconcile these two facts which seem contradictory at first sight.

Answer (score 0):

Get a pulse-width modulated (PWM) speed controlLer. This techniques changes the duty cycle of the input voltage to give an "average" voltage that is lower. There is a huge advantage to PWM vs simply decreasing the voltage in that you get better Low-speed control because the motor is getting the higher voltage for short bursts.  Typically. PWM frequency is 8 to 20k Hz and on vs off duty cycle is controlled.  For very low speed control, you can bring the PWM frequency down to 60Hz or less in larger motors that have lots of inertia that may not start well at low duty cycles.
You can find low priced pwm controllers on Amazon or eBay.

Finally, just because someone calls a 12v motor a 12v motors, doesn't mean it can't be run at 8 or 9v at a lower speed just fine. Some motors are rated in rpm per volt.

Comment: I use these motors for model railroading, which has a fixed top voltage of 12V. PWM is already used to control speed via DCC control.  I just want all locomotives to run at about the same speed at maximum voltage (PWM = 100% duty cycle).

Comment: @Pygmalion Better DCC controllers have throttle curves to match locos. I have bought many small motors from eBay to re-power my N scale locos. At this smaller scale 9000rpm at 6V is perfect, so I would think 6000-9000rpm at 12V would be fine for HO/OO. However the motor should have carbon brushes for long lifespan. Try searching eBay for eg. "DC 6V-24V 12000RPM Micro FK-130PH" or "FK-130PH-11405 DC6V 3200rpm" or "FK-130SH-09450 DC24V 15000RPM".

Comment: Motors are rated a given RPM under no load.  Adding the weight of the loco with its gears will definitely slow the motor.  The internal design of the motor (length of armature, number of windings, wire resistance, strength of magnet and resistance of brushes and more all play a role in how fast the motor will spin under load.  My recommendation is to install the motor, then measure speed and current draw at the power supply. Then add a low-value power resistor to slow the loco to an acceptable speed.  I can help with resistor selection once you measure the current and speed (and target speed).

Comment: @BruceAbbott The problem is that my antique locomotives have very low gear ratios, 1:13 or 1:8.5.  So I really need low RPM in order to get good performace of the motor.  Running a motor at less than 6V all the time is not very efficient.

Comment: @GTElectronics This is a very inefficient solution as half of the energy will be lost on the resistor as a heat and performance of the motor will be much worse.  Plus there is a problem of heat dissipance.

Comment: Series resistor has been used in some commercial locos, but it is not a good solution because it limits torque and causes poor speed regulation. High frequency PWM can be very efficient when applied locally (ie. via the onboard DCC decoder). It increases motor current relative to supply current (effectively 'transforming' to lower voltage and higher current using the motor's winding inductance) which improves torque at lower rpm and varying load. Some DCC decoders can also measure generated voltage ('back-emf') during PWM 'off' time, to provide closed-loop speed regulation.

Comment: @BruceAbbott all true but, how does PWM work on a PWM signal?  Read the OP's responses and you'll see that the locos are already PWM speed controlled. He wants a method to match the speeds of the unmatched motors. I've never attempted an onboard pwm of a rail-fed PWM supply,  doesn't seem quite right and a simple resistor to trim the speed seems soooo much easier.

Comment: @GTElectronics resistor is a terrible solution. DCC decoders do PWM _in the loco_ fed from constant 12VDC (rectified DCC square wave power/signal), and the good ones can be tuned to match the speed range and throttle curve required. So the answer is - get a good DCC decoder and learn how to program it!

Comment: But that is not what the OP described, is it?